# Scrap Your Boilerplate in f#

Tags: f#, generic-programming, discriminated-union, scrap-your-boilerplate

I've used the [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/hmap/) and Uniplate libraries in the Haskell programming language, and I would find that form of generic programming over discriminated unions to be really useful.  Is there an equivalent library in the f# programming language?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not that I know of; without support built-in to the language/compiler, I expect the only alternative is a reflection-based version.  (I don't know how [Uniplate](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/uniplate/) is implemented - do you?)

Here's the code for a reflection-based version based on the example from the original presentation.  I have not thought deeply about its limitations, but this was much simpler to write than I would have guessed.

```
type Company = C of Dept list
and Dept = D of Name * Manager * SubUnit list
and SubUnit = | PU of Employee | DU of Dept
and Employee = E of Person * Salary
and Person = P of Name * Address
and Salary = S of float
and Manager = Employee
and Name = string
and Address = string

let data = C [D("Research",E(P("Fred","123 Rose"),S 10.0),
                  [PU(E(P("Bill","15 Oak"),S 5.0))])]
printfn "%A" data

open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection 
let everywhere<'a,'b>(f:'a->'a, src:'b) =   // '
    let ft = typeof<'a>             // '
    let rec traverse (o:obj) =
        let ot = o.GetType()
        if ft = ot then
            f (o :?> 'a) |> box    // '
        elif FSharpType.IsUnion(ot) then
            let info,vals = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(o, ot)
            FSharpValue.MakeUnion(info, vals |> Array.map traverse)
        else 
            o
    traverse src :?> 'b       // '

let incS (S x) = S(x+1.0) 

let newData = everywhere(incS, data)
printfn "%A" newData
```

The `everywhere` function traverses the entire structure of an arbitrary DU and applies the function `f` to each node that is the type that `f` works on, leaving all other nodes as-is.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I'll have to think about the performance implications of such an approach.  It probably doesn't matter for my particular usecase anyway.

Comment: re: your question about how Uniplate is implemented the source is available at http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/uniplate/ .

Comment: I've accepted your answer since I think its a good approach - but I make a change in order to get it to work correctly:

I replaced 'ft = ot' with 'ot.IsSubclassOf(ft)' - otherwise it fails to match when the argument type of f, ie 'a is more generic than the specific argument being passed.

Comment: To a first approximation, Uniplate is implemented with magic. :] That said, Uniplate, SYB, and related libraries mostly exist as structured, explicit implementations of what reflection does. No special support is needed in Haskell (auto-generation of instances is merely a convenience), but I don't know if the techniques used exist in F#, and either way I expect it would be more sensible to just build on top of the existing facilities for reflection, as in your example here.

Comment: See also http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fsharpgeneral/thread/742480f0-067c-4f2e-aae8-c41452840b09