# Is there anything like Haskell generic programming for F#?

Tags: haskell, f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scrap Your Boilerplate in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596718/scrap-your-boilerplate-in-f)

I'm missing the sort generic traversal and transformation libraries that I have in Haskell when I'm working in F#.

Has anyone looked at doing something like Uniplate/Biplate for F#?

There's a brief mention in the comments of one of Neil Mitchell's blog posts, but I never found any further development:

http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/09/general-updates.html

I imagine you could build something on .NET reflection instead of type-classes, but I don't want to dig too deep without looking at prior art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

[Scrap Your Boilerplate in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596718/scrap-your-boilerplate-in-f)

Comment: Looks like I used the wrong search term. Thanks.