# Attribute Grammar System in F#

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, functional-programming, grammar

after searching the web i could not find an attribute grammar system for F#. Well there is fsyacc with inherited attributes but i am looking for something more expressive like Ox ([Ox manual](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.29.4873)). Actually i would prefer an embedded approach (maybe coupled with fparsec). Well i could go with haskell and the excellent utrecht attribute grammar system ([UHC attribute grammar system](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/HUT/AttributeGrammarSystem)) but for some reasons i would like to stick with f#.

Note: right now i am using catamorphisms (and dozens of handwritten traversals) all the way in my compiler the code complexity is...just enormous ;-)

any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 'dozens of handwritten traversals', I don't know if it's exactly related, but check out

[Scrap Your Boilerplate in f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596718/scrap-your-boilerplate-in-f)

in case it helps or provides inspiration.

Comment: well it is releated in the sense that the presented answer really reduces my code like suggested. Anyway i would prefer a more declarative approach for tree transformations.